# Externally adding a project to part of the build hierarchy

Tags: groovy, build, gradle

I have a central project, containing several modules, and several auxiliary projects:

```
central/
    a/
    b/
    c/
auxiliary/
    d/
    e/
    f/
```

The auxiliary projects depend on the central project, but the central project cannot reference the auxiliary projects in any way.

How can I setup the `gradle.build` files in auxiliary such that the dependencies in central are resolved and built correctly?

For example, I'm building `auxiliary:d` and it depends on `central:b`, which depends on `central:a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `central` and `auxiliary` have separate source repositories. In that case, the standard solution is to publish `central` modules to a (local or remote) Maven/Ivy repository, and have `auxiliary` resolve it from there. If you sometimes want this to be a source dependency (i.e. have a single build/IDE project for `auxiliary` and `central`), check out Prezi's [Pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride) tool.

Comment: Is there a way to set it up as source dependency without an external tool? Or is that not possible with gradle?

Comment: Currently this isn't supported out-of-the-box, but there are plans to support it in the future.